# How to change label direction in the OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I have an `OutlinedTextField` in jetpack compose and I want to change the label direction to the right of `OutlinedTextField` for the Persian language (By default is on the left).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl)`.

**Sample code,**

```
@Composable
fun RtlLabelInOutlineTextField() {
    val (digit1, setDigit1) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = digit1,
            onValueChange = {
                setDigit1(it)
            },
            label = {
                Text("Label")
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
        )
    }
}
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Screenshots]
[image: Screenshots]
[image: Screenshots]